# Can a random passerby enter a Rope Trick or Psychoportive Shelter?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, powers, planes

Both effects have similar natures, end results, and wording. However, nothing in the wording of either power or spell seems to indicate that someone can't come in wherever, assuming that they can reach the interface, pass through the plane of the interface, and assuming there is room for one more.

Area of effects and other special effects cannot cross the interface, as described, and the interface is one way visually (even when invisible), but the entrance of another creature after the fact does not seem to be contradicted?

Thus, can a random passerby enter a Rope Trick or Psychoportive Shelter, accidentally, or on purpose?

Comment: do any of these answer your question? If so, you might want to select them as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you as the DM. As you've said, the spell's rules don't explicitly contradict the possibility of entering by another means. Pulling up the rope causes it to *disappear from view*, but doesn't explicitly prohibit entry.

Personally, I would rule that it's not possible to enter the space apart from via the rope. The spell description specifies that

> The extradimensional space can be reached by climbing to the top of the rope

and doesn't specify any other means of entry. I would interpret that as excluding other means of entry, because I interpret that as one of the spell's benefits and I wouldn't want to take that away from my players. This is also consistent with the *extradimensional* nature of the space created by the spell - it can't necessarily be entered through simple travel through the dimensions of space.

The PHB (pg. 68, *Demiplanes*) specifies that such extradimensional spaces are demiplanes, meaning it would be possible to enter via the *Plane Shift* (with the correct tuning fork) or *Gate* spells.

Answer (score -1):

This is a strangely worded question.

Rope trick defines that anyone who climbs the rope can enter the extradimensional space.  If the rope is gone (pulled free, or the GM allows it to be 'pulled up inside' the rope trick) that could be used to argue that the space does not allow anyone entry.  However the references to a '3 by 5 foot window' and in general that extra dimensional spaces in dnd 3.5 are always gateways or openings into this space and that exceptions to this rule typically call themselves out as such (such as Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion) mean that I would rarely or never expect anyone to assume such.

In use I have always seen the expectation and assumption be that the '3 by 5 foot window' is the entry point to the rope trick extradimensional space - and can be moved through by any of the traditional means one would use to enter a 3 by 5 foot window that is 5'-30' off the ground.

Comment: Thus a random passing swallow (African or European) could accidentally enter, assuming a creature space is available?

Comment: depends if it is carrying an awakened coconut